# pointer to member strange declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I've recently seen the following code:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> 
class Functor
{
    Functor( T1 T2::* t): memPointer(t) {}
    bool operator() ( const T2 &obj1, const T2 &obj )
    {

        return obj1.*memPointer < (obj.*memPointer);

    }

    T1 T2::* memPointer;
};
```

Here `Functor` is used as a generic functor for sorting objects with respect to a data member, i.e. it's used like

```
struct ABC
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<ABC> v; 
    // initialize v with ABCs
    Functor<double, ABC> fun(&ABC::x);
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), fun); // sort with respect to `ABC::x`
}
```

I have to say that I don't understand how `Functor` works. More specifically, what is the type of the `Functor::Functor` constructor? `T2::*` should be a pointer-to-member, but then why is it qualified with `T1`? I admit I haven't seen this syntax before.

Comment: `T1 T2::*` is "pointer to member of class T2 of type T1".

Comment: @T.C. ahh ok, I get it now, you have to specify its type, as `T2::*` just tells you that you have a pointer-to-member and not a "regular" pointer. It is actually consistent with the pointer-to-member-function, where you also specify the signature of the function. It's the first time I'm seeing a pointer-to-member used in real code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the bog-standard pointer to member syntax.

Consider a normal pointer:

```
int *
```

Here, `*` tells you it's a pointer; `int` tells you the type of the object it points to. Now, in

```
T1 T2::*
```

`T2::*` tells you it's a pointer to member of the class `T2`. It's just like the `*` in normal pointers. What's the type of the member it points to? `T1`, just like `int` in `int *`.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers to members define how to access the particular member on an object of the type, compared with regular pointers that give the absolute address of an object.  To be able to access the member you need two elements, the pointer-to-member and the object on which you will apply it.

The declaration `T U::*` means that this is a *mechanism* to access a member of type `T` inside an object of type `U`.  Both types are needed, as the `T` determines what will be accessed, and `U` is needed to know *how* to access it. In particular, in the presence of inheritance, you can use a pointer-to-member to base with an object of type derived and the compiler will do the right thing whether the base and the derived type are aligned or not:

```
struct base { int member; }                          b;
struct derived1 : base {}                            d1;
struct derived2 : base { virtual void ~derived2(); } d2;
struct anotherbase { int y; };
struct derived3 : anotherbase, base {}               d3;
```

In the code above the address of the complete object `d1` and its base subobject is the same, in both `d2` and `d3` the base is not aligned with the derived type, in the case of `d2` due to the `vptr`, in the case of `d3` due to the presence of `anotherbase`.

```
int base::*ptm = &base::member;
b .*ptm = 5;
d1.*ptm = 10;
d2.*ptm = 15;
d3.*ptm = 20;
```

When the compiler encounters `b.*ptm` it applies the pointer to member `ptm` to the object `b` and yields `b.member`. There is no arithmetic required to find where the member lives. The same happens when it encounters `d1.*ptm`, since the base and the complete object are aligned.  When it encounters `d2.*ptm` or `d3.*ptm` the compiler will first calculate the address of the base subobject (pointer arithmetic) and then apply the pointer to member to that address.  The type `base::*` is what indicates what conversion (offset, or dynamic calculation in the case of virtual inheritance) needs to be done.
In this simplified example where the real objects are accessible any compiler worth its name will actually inject the addresses of the members directly, but if this was in a different translation unit, and accessed through a reference the above description would apply.

Other than that, the `Functor` that you created will have bad performance characteristics in general, as you are storing the pointer to member and forcing it to be used. You would be better off converting the pointer-to-member to a template argument so that the compiler has better information to optimize.  Alternatively, you could avoid the functor altogether and just use a *lambda* that will have good performance and is probably simpler to understand for the maintainer of your code:

```
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 
          [](ABC const& lhs, ABC const & rhs) {
               return lhs.x < rhs.x;
          });
```

This will also make it more obvious at the place of call that you are only using the `x` member and might bring up the question of whether you should be resoving *ties* `lhs.x == rhs.x` with the second member…